# How to implement custom writable's write and readFields for a map or list of custom object?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a wrapper class that contains the following

```
class myWrapperClass {
    Map<Long, myInnerClass> myMap;
    int myInt1;
    int myInt2;
}

class myInnerClass {
    int myInnerInt;
    long myInnerLong;
}
```

I want to have a `customWritable` so far I have the following

```
@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeInt(this.myInt1);
    out.writeInt(this.myInt2);
    // What do I do here
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    myInt1 = in.readInt();
    myInt2 = in.readShort();
    // What do I do here
}
```

I am not sure how I would write to and read from `DataOutput` if I have a custom object.

Can someone point me a direction?

Comment: I would suggest using Avro, which natively supports maps and arrays